# Нужна помощь с изображениями в python

Tags: python, tkinter

Решил я создать программку с GUI где можно просматривать фотографии которые парсируются на компьютер и записываются в словарь. Проблема заключается в том, что у меня не получается сделать так чтобы при вызове функции переключения картинки картинка менялась

UPD:
код с созданием картинки нужно вставить в new_window_pic()

код:

```
def update_pics_list():
    content = requests.get(URL).text
    imgUrls = re.findall('img .*?src="(.*?)"', content)
    # Максимально для меня возможная отчистка
    """for el in imgUrls:
        if 'avatar' in str(el):
            imgUrls.remove(el)
        elif 'user' in str(el):
            imgUrls.remove(el)
        elif 'pics/avatar/user/' in str(el):
            imgUrls.remove(el)
            """
    imgUrls = imgUrls[3:]
    print(imgUrls)
    return imgUrls

# запись картинки из массива картинок
def new_window_pic(x):
    os.remove('image.jpeg')
    with open('image.jpeg','wb') as pic:
        img = urllib.request.urlopen(update_pics_list()[x]).read()
        pic.write(img)

# Первая картинка
new_window_pic(0)
# Создание окна
windowMain = Tk()
windowMain.geometry('900x700')

# Создание рамки search
search_frame = Frame(windowMain)
search_frame.grid()

# Создание текстового поля search
search_txt= Entry(search_frame, width=30)

# Создание кнопки search
search_btn = Button(search_frame,text="search",command=search)

# Рамка кнопок и картинки
main_frame = Frame(windowMain)

# Кнопки перемещения по картинкам
btn_prew = Button(windowMain,command=cntr.prew,text='prew')
btn_next = Button(windowMain,command=cntr.next,text='next')

# pack всего
search_frame.pack()
search_txt.pack()
search_btn.pack()
btn1.pack(side='left')
btn2.pack(side='left')
btn_next.pack(side='bottom')
btn_prew.pack(side='bottom')
main_frame.pack()

# Картинка
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image.jpeg'))
view = tkinter.Label(main_frame, image=img)
view.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")


print("started")

# Запуск программы
windowMain.mainloop()
```

Comment: добавь свой код

Comment: вот посмотрите [простое slideshow, используя tkinter](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c). В вашем случае, попробуйте: `view.configure(image=img)`